# How to select left table, order by max date of the right table and max date is less than or equal to NOW()?

Tags: mysql, select

Below are my database tables

```
left_table
id    name
1     A
2     B
3     C
4     D
5     E

right_table
id    left_table_id     size      date_time
1     1                 xs        2017-06-13 14:20:00
2     3                 s         2017-06-13 14:25:00
3     2                 xs        2017-06-13 14:27:00
4     1                 s         2017-06-13 14:30:00
5     2                 m         2017-06-13 14:32:00
6     2                 xs        2017-06-13 14:33:00
7     3                 xl        2017-06-13 14:40:00
8     4                 s         2017-06-13 14:41:00
9     4                 m         2017-06-13 14:45:00
10    5                 m         2017-06-13 14:46:00
```

How to write the sql query to get the records of the `left_table` order by the `max(date_time) DESC` where `date_time <= NOW()` as the following result.

```
result left_table order by max(add_time) DESC 
id    name    max(add_time)   
2     B       2017-06-13 14:33:00
1     A       2017-06-13 14:30:00
3     C       2017-06-13 14:25:00
```

This is because `date_time` of left_table_id of 4 and 5 is > NOW(). Assume `NOW() = 2017-06-13 14::35:00`. Note that left_table_id `3` has one `add_time > NOW()` but it is still being selected because it has other right record, `add_time <= NOW()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, r.date_time
FROM left_table AS t
JOIN (
   SELECT id, MAX(date_time) AS date_time
   FROM right_table
   WHERE date_time <= NOW() 
   GROUP BY id) AS r ON t.id = r.id
ORDER BY r.date_time DESC;
```

The query uses a derived table which filters out records that have a `date_time` value that is past the current timestamp. It also group records in order to get the latest `date_time` value per `id`. Using this derived table we can easily perform the sorting required using its `date_time` field.